# BAT files: path of argument

Tags: batch-file

How can I get the directory of the argument set to a bat file, considering that the argument is file path relative to the current dir?

For example I have the following files:

```
C:\folder1\mybat.bat
C:\folder2\x.jpg

from C:\ I run: folder1\mybat.bat folder2\x.jpg
Now I want to get: C:\folder2 because that's the folder of x.jpg

from C:\folder1 I run: mybat.bat ..\folder2\x.jpg
Result is the same as above

from C:\folder2 I run: ..\folder1\mybat.bat x.jpg
Result is again the same, the folder of x
```

Comment: Have you checked out [Windows PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) yet? It's far more powerful than batch files or the command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

`%~dp1` should give you what you want.

Actually you can do `help call` and see lots of options around this. Description of `%~dp1` -

> %~dp1       - expands %1 to a drive
>   letter and path only